# Sonata Media Youtube Provider validation in controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I created my own Youtube Provider with some constraints, it works like a charm in admin panel.

[image: Youtube provider work in Admin panel]

My provider use the validate function :

```
public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, MediaInterface $media)
{
    if ($this->videoIsTooLong($media)) {
        $errorElement
            ->with('length')
            ->addViolation("La vidéo ne doit pas dépasser 10 minutes.")
            ->end();
    }

    if(!$this->isEmbeddable($media)) {
        $errorElement
            ->with('provider_metadata')
            ->addViolation("La vidéo n'est pas embeddable.")
            ->end();
    }
}
```

I found how to create a media in documentation https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/usage.html

**My problem :** How to handle this validate method ? I think I should use/create a Form, submit and use $form->isValid() something like that but I'm lost.

Thank you.

Comment: did you solve it?? thanks!!

Comment: @jjgarcía no :s

Comment: thanks, I solved creating custom validation for this kind of fields